# rewrite $n \ln(\frac{1}{2 \theta^3})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$n \ln(\frac{1}{2 \theta^3}) = n \ln (1) - 3n \ln (2\theta)$

why is this not right?

apparently the answer is $-n \ln (2) - 3 n \ln (\theta)$

Comment: Note that $3n \ln(2\theta) = n \ln(2^3\theta^3)$

Answer (score 1):

$n\ln(\frac{1}{2{\theta}^3})$ can be written as $n\ln(2^{-1}{\theta}^{-3})$.So according to the rule $$\ln(xy)=\ln{x}+\ln{y}$$, you will get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$n\ln\left(\frac{1}{2\theta^3}\right)=n\left(\ln(1)-\ln(2\theta^3)\right)=n\left(-\ln(2)-3\ln(\theta)\right)$$

Comment: is this equivalent tho? : "$n \ln (1) - 3n \ln (2\theta)$"

Comment: Yes since $$n\ln(1)-3n\ln(2\theta)=-3n\ln(2\theta)=-3n(\ln(2)+\ln(\theta))$$

Answer (score 0):

The exponent $3$ is only on $\theta$, not on the $2$, so you can't pull it out like that.  You have to split off the $2$ first:

$$\ln(2\theta^3) = \ln 2 + \ln \theta^3 = \ln 2+3\ln \theta.$$

Next, note that $\ln 1 = 0.$

So you should have

$$n\ln \frac{1}{2\theta^3} = n\ln 1 - n\ln(2\theta^3)$$

and then plug in the above.